# subprocess.call() - Could not parse JSON (lexical error: invalid char in json text.)

Tags: python, json, subprocess

I'm trying to modify a python script to run a shell program, I do this with subprocess.call() like this:

```
def on_leftclick(self):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call("mpc toggle", shell=True)
```

And I get this error when I left-click:

```
Could not parse JSON (lexical error: invalid char in json text.)
```

This is done in i3pystatus, a program that connects with i3bar (a part of the i3 window manager), I have already modified another script and it worked, an example:

```
def on_upscroll(self):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call("pamixer --increase 1 --allow-boost", shell=True)
```

Also, I tried doing this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("mpc toggle", shell=True)
```

in the python shell and it worked, so I don't get what the problem is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `mpc` program is probably throwing that error. Make sure you are calling it correctly.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo `mpc toggle` works, just tested that now.

Comment: @Anzel It just does nothing.

Comment: @shogam, perhaps you can show code/samples what `mpc` and `toggle` are? In general using `shell=True` isn't recommended

Comment: `mpc` is a program for linux, a media player client (for the terminal). `toggle` is an action for the client, which toggles between playing and pausing the song. I use `shell=True` because it's meant to run in a terminal, and as far as I can see, `mpc toggle` doesn't work when `shell` is `False`.

Comment: @shoham, ah ok. I use Linux but have never known what `mpc` is. Better leave this to someone will relevant experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by doing this in the i3pystatus module:

```
subprocess.call("mpc toggle") # parameter shell=True or False, doesn't matter
```

Because the [subprocess.call()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function by default passes the `stdout` and `stderr` file handles of the parent process (i.e. `i3pystatus`) to the new child (`mpc`), all the output from your `mpc` call get dumped into `i3pystatus`'s own output. This output is supposed to be valid JSON, but now has a big unexpected chunk of random console spew in it. This results in the output of `i3pystatus` failing to parse as JSON.*

You have two options:

### Use `subprocess` to capture/dispose of the sub-process's output

Dispose of it:

```
def on_leftclick(self):
    subprocess.call("mpc toggle", shell=True, 
                    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

or, if you want the output, [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
def on_leftclick(self):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['mpc', 'toggle'],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate() # .decode() these to strings if appropriate
    retcode = p.returncode
```

### Use the `run_through_shell` helper in i3pystatus

i3pystatus provides a helper to wrap `subprocess` for you: [i3pystatus.core.command.run_through_shell](https://i3pystatus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i3pystatus.core.html#i3pystatus.core.command.run_through_shell):

```
from i3pystatus.core.command import run_through_shell

def on_leftclick(self):
    run_through_shell(["mpc", "toggle"])
```

or, to get your shell to do the parsing of the command, give it the string:

```
def on_leftclick(self):
    run_through_shell("mpc toggle", enable_shell=True)
```

You can also get the return code and stdout/stderr outputs easily, for you own nefarious purposes:

```
def on_leftclick(self):
    retcode, out, err = run_through_shell(["mpc", "toggle"])
    # out and err are already decoded to UTF-8 - you can't use this
    # method if that's not true, e.g. if it's binary data
```

To be fair, `run_through_shell` didn't exist until the year after the question was asked (it was [added in December 2014](https://github.com/enkore/i3pystatus/commit/bc15eb4e6b051f557567aca767a1160939c0f6d7#diff-540aa0f57e63c9d14b4c9ee9965ba1dd)). i3pystatus uses both methods in the codebase.

> TL;DR: Make sure your subprocess isn't spewing output into
>   `i3pystatus`'s own output, because that needs to be valid JSON.

* Probably fails in [this call](https://github.com/enkore/i3pystatus/blob/0f4480e9916690cf5610d8a18cc1c2ce6768491f/i3pystatus/core/io.py#L201) to json.loads(), but I haven't proved that.